# Casting File (archivo PDF) a arreglo de byte

Tags: java, spring-boot

Me ayudarían como Convertir un archivo PDF a arreglo de Bytes, el archivo lo tengo almacenado en un folder de resources, tengo lo siguiente pero no encuentro una buena manera de realiza el casting.

```
@Override
public byte[] convertir() throws Exception {
    byte[] data = null;
    File file = new ClassPathResource("/archivos/tarea.pdf").getFile();
    data = ?????;
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En vez de usar el método `getFile()` usa el que te devuelve ya un `InputStream` sobre el que puedes leer los datos.

Si usas Java 9, o superior:

```
// Omito todo el manejo de excepciones por simplicidad
byte[] data = new ClassPathResource("/archivos/tarea.pdf").getInputStream().readAllBytes();
```

Si usas Java 8, o inferior, vas a tener que leer el contenido como se ha hecho tradicionalmente:

```
// Omito todo el manejo de excepciones por simplicidad
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
int readed;
while ((readed = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    baos.write(buffer, 0, readed);
}

// No olvides liberar los recursos
```